# Roadmap to learn CNN in tensorflow from scratch

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I'm working in the medical field and I'd like to learn applications of CNN for image recognition and classification. All the (few) things I learned come from self-learning on the web or sparse books. I'm studying now Tensorflow for CNN implementation but I'm having trouble finding clear documentation for my actual level, so I think I'm missing the basic knowledge in order to understand this.

I'm at a basic level of python programming, I have better understanding of classical machine learning algorithms, which resources should I learn in order to get a good grasp of the argument? Is there such an ideal pathway to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about medical images classification, rather than localization.

Personally I recommend [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), it has an awesome forum and people share their codes and opinions there.

You can start at [Digit Recognizer](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer), it's actually the well-known MNIST dataset(hand-written numbers). There's no relationship between MNIST and medical field. However there are some common techniques and tricks as they are both image recognition/classification problems.

If you encounter problems, read the other ones' codes at the `kernel` section, especially those with upvotes.

In the meanwhile, comment section is a good place to learn. I learned a lot there when I started to learn CNN.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, do you know more structured sources of information like books? I'm having a difficult time learning from spot sources

Comment: For structured sources, I highly recommend Stanford's CS231n. It's an amazing lecture with details. You can checkout the videos at [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLvH2FwAQhnpj1WEB-jHmPuUeQ8mX-XXG). And Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Yearning might help you when you become familier with neural networks.